# Can you say “what was —- a reaction to?”

Tags: meaning, phrase-usage, agreement

If I mean to ask the main causes of something, so I want to know what something reacted to, can I say “what was the war a reaction to?”? It sounds pretty weird to me...  I’d rather say “what did the war react to?” Are they both right? Are they both wrong?